# Format of the circuit symbol size option argument in tikz circuits

Tags: tikz-pgf

The value or argument associated with the tikz circuits key *circuit symbol size* describes the width and height of a symbol in non-dimensional terms.  An example of the argument's format is `width 10 height 3`.  I would like to assign variables to the width and height of the symbol.  On attempting to compile the following code, I find that an expression like `width \symbolwidtha height \symbolheighta` where

```
\def\symbolwidtha{13}
\def\symbolheighta{1.5}
```

returns an error.  How does one control the size of the symbol using predefined variables?

```
\documentclass[tikz,convert=false]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{circuits,circuits.ee.IEC}
\begin{document}
\newlength{\circuitunit}
\setlength{\circuitunit}{0.32cm}

%\edef\symbolwidtha{13}
%\edef\symbolheighta{1.5}

%\def\symbolwidtha{13}
%\def\symbolheighta{1.5}

\begin{tikzpicture}[circuit ee IEC]
%\node[resistor,circuit symbol size=width \symbolwidtha height \symbolheighta] at (0,0) (theresistora) {};% does not compile
%\node[resistor,width=\symbolwidtha,height=\symbolheighta] at (0,0) (theresistora) {};% does not compile
\node[resistor,circuit symbol unit=\circuitunit] at (0,1) (theresistorb) {};
\node[resistor,circuit symbol size=width 12 height 2,circuit symbol unit=6pt] at (0,2) (theresistorc) {};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In the first case, the space before `height` is lost, you need to do either

```
circuit symbol size=width {\symbolwidtha} height \symbolheighta
```

or

```
circuit symbol size/.expanded=width \symbolwidtha\space height \symbolheighta
```

the first method being the preferred one.